# Exactness of the lie algebra functor

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, homological-algebra

A question that occurs naturally but of which I (and, apparently, Google too) does not know an answer is the following: is the functor that associates to a lie Group its lie Algebra an exact functor?
I would guess the answer is not true, and that it is only left exact.
What can be said about the exactness properties of this functor?

Comment: The category of Lie groups itself just has very few colimits (e.g. it doesn't have coproducts) so I don't even know what would be gained from knowing if the Lie algebra functor preserved them. It is true, and not hard to see, that the Lie algebra functor sends short exact sequences of Lie groups to short exact sequences of Lie algebras.

Comment: A surjection of Lie groups is mapped to a surjection of Lie algebras, at least.

Comment: A references is [here](https://books.google.at/books?id=fJyqSkEexNgC&pg=PA189&lpg=PA189&dq=is+the+Lie+functor++exact+?&source=bl&ots=4d71OcITDb&sig=rdM3acpDQ-kfdljzLp0aphCzAmg&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0CFkQ6AEwB2oVChMImsDZ843ZyAIVRTcUCh1W-ARZ#v=onepage&q=is%20the%20Lie%20functor%20%20exact%20%3F&f=false), also the functor from pro-Lie groups to pro-Lie algebras is exact (Theorem $4.20$).